# performance comparison with perf-stat

Tags: perf

please check the below code.
the code be implemented with two solutions. one is array, the other one is linking list.

i expected the array version should be faster than the linking list one,
because the cache miss.

i used Perf program to check. but the result is not what i think.
please check the below Perf output.

the cache miss of the linking list version is higher than the array version, indeed.
however, the linking list version is more faster. i do not know why.

please help interpreting the both Perf output, and illustrating why.

thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef ARRAY
static int *head = NULL;
static int prime_size = 0;
#elif LINKING_LIST
struct prime {
        int value;
        struct prime *next;
};

static struct prime *head = NULL;
static struct prime *tail = NULL;
#endif

static bool is_prime(int n)
{
        int i = 0;
        int half = n / 2;

        if (n <= 1)
                return false;

#ifdef ARRAY
        for (i = 0; i < prime_size && head[i] <= half; i++) {
                if (!(n % head[i]))
                        return false;
        }
#elif LINKING_LIST
        struct prime *tmp = head;

        while (tmp && tmp->value <= half) {
                if (!(n % tmp->value))
                        return false;

                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
#endif

        return true;
}

static void stash(int p)
{
#ifdef ARRAY
        head = (int *)realloc(head, ++prime_size * sizeof(int));
        head[prime_size - 1] = p;
#elif LINKING_LIST
        struct prime *tmp = (struct prime *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct prime));
        tmp->next = NULL;
        tmp->value = p;

        if (!head)
                head = tail = tmp;
        else {
                tail->next = tmp;
                tail = tmp;
        }
#endif
}

int countPrimes(int n)
{
        int retval = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (is_prime(i)) {
                        stash(i);
                        retval += 1;
                }
        }

        return retval;
}

int main(void)
{
        int input = 499979;
        printf("%d ->  %d\n", input, countPrimes(input));

        return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid the misuse of proper nouns. The above program contains a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), which is a sequence of nodes that contain two fields: an integer value and a link to the next node. That is the reason why it is called a "linked" list rather than a "linking" list. [realloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3p.html) was heavily called in your program, which has a detrimental effect. If you would like to fairly compare with an array and a linked list, you should eliminate unintended memory allocations in the iterations. That is, memory (de-)allocations should happen at the very beginning and the end of a program.

Comment: thanks for correcting misuse nouns! 

you are right. i do not consider this part.
let me check, thanks!

Comment: Hi @jserv,

i modified the code, like [v0.0.2](https://github.com/manbing/LeetCode/commit/958daf8949709caa4d5eaf134cadc96a14986c5e).

the linked list version is faster than array version still.

after that, i do another test.
i removed traversing array/linked list part, like [v0.0.3](https://github.com/manbing/LeetCode/commit/129d34e239e67e9e7295e8874332023ce3ab7296).


the linked list version is slower than array version, it is expectation, because calloc was called heavily, as you mention before.

Comment: base on test [v0.0.2](https://github.com/manbing/LeetCode/commit/958daf8949709caa4d5eaf134cadc96a14986c5e) and [v0.0.3](https://github.com/manbing/LeetCode/commit/129d34e239e67e9e7295e8874332023ce3ab7296),
does it mean the cost of traversing array is higher than linked list one?
it sounds a little strange.

Comment: The experiments need to be improved: memory allocations should appear before you are about to traverse, otherwise you can only figure out the impact due to frequent library calls.

Comment: yes, you are right.
for my purpose, i should measure time of traversing part only.
i will use perf-probe to measure the part code again.
thanks!